# can we do something like Terraform Plan in Serverless?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless, serverless-framework, cicd

when I change something in my lambda repo and redeploy the lambda with serverless framework it make changes. I want to know the changes that going to happen prior to deploying the lambda.

I tried serverless changeset plugin, but it doesn't show a comparison between my current lambda configuration and the changes going to happen by deploying the lambda after making some changes in my lambda repo [e.g. the lambda name, tags etc.]

Answer (score 1):

You can enable changesets with `deploymentMethod: changesets` so that `serverless deploy` doesn't actually execute the changes, but instead creates a changeset inside CloudFormation which you can inspect inside the console and then initiate from there.

Edit: This is unfortunately no longer supported in the latest versions of Serverless as of 2023.